# PHP extract domain of request (including HTTP) Laravel5.3

Tags: php, dns, request, extract, laravel-5.3

I'm saving a list of domains in my database like:

```
id|domain
1 http://xyz.or
2 http://xyz.ne
3 http://xyz.pw
```

Now when a user visits a website of I would need to get the domain of his request in this format so I can search database for existence.

What's the best way to extract the domain so I can perform a check for the above database design (domains contain subdomains too)?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using `$request->root()`, where the request is type of `Illuminate\Http\Request`